# How to set bios serialmunber as user password

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a local user account and set the password as bios *serialnumber*.

```
$Password = Get-WmiObject win32_bios | select serialnumber | Out-String
New-LocalUser -Name Altran -Password $Password
```

And get this error

```
PS C:\windows\system32> $Password = Get-WmiObject win32_bios | select serialnumber | Out-String

New-LocalUser -Name Altran -Password $Password


New-LocalUser : Cannot bind parameter 'Password'. Cannot convert the "
serialnumber
------------
PF0IKYXC    
" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Security.SecureString".
At line:3 char:38
+ New-LocalUser -Name Altran -Password $Password
+                                      ~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [New-LocalUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConvertArgumentNoMessage,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewLocalUserCommand
```

Can any one give me a help? I'm stuck on this.

Answer (score 0):

1) Instead of this:

```
$Password = Get-WmiObject win32_bios | select serialnumber | Out-String
```

You want this:

```
$Password = Get-WmiObject Win32_BIOS | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SerialNumber
```

Why? You want to select the property of the object (`Select-Object -ExpandProperty`) rather than `Out-String`.

2) Instead of this:

```
New-LocalUser -Name Altran -Password $Password
```

You want this:

```
New-LocalUser -Name Altran -Password ($Password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
```

This is because the `-Password` parameter requires a `SecureString` object. (NOTE: I have not tested this.)

3) This is pretty insecure. I don't think I would recommend doing things this way.

Comment: Tanks for the help i know this is not secured but the company polici is to give local admin password for users not domain admin.

Comment: Give users local admin access to their individual machines with their own user identity rather than telling them the pwd is the hardware serial number. Just asking this question and sharing that knowledge of what you're doing opens your company up to being exploited relatively simply.

Comment: Adam Parsons is quite right. This is a bad idea and a substantial security hole. Use this answer to understand PowerShell better, but you should definitely _not_ do this.